# Use Jquery to get values in a code that has a different organization

Tags: jquery

I want to use Jquery to get information from the code below:

```
<div id="filtro_informacoes">

        <div class="categoria_filtro">
            <b>Category 1</b>
        </div>

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 1</b>
        </div>

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 2</b>
        </div>      

        <div class="categoria_filtro">
            <b>Category 2</b>
        </div>  

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 3</b>
        </div>

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 4</b>
        </div>

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 5</b>
        </div>

        <div class="curso_filtro">
            <b>Course 6</b>
        </div>
</div>
```

In the code, "Category 1" is the 'father' of "Course 1" and "Course 2". 
"Category 2" is the 'father' of "Course 3", "Course 4", "Course 5", "Course 6".

I try to use the component "each" from Jquery to get result, the code used is the code below:

```
var filterObject = $("#filtro_informacoes");
    $.each( filterObject, function( key ) {
        var cat_text = $(this).children('.categoria_filtro').text();
        console.log( key + ": " + cat_text );
        var filtro_curso = $(this).children('.curso_filtro').text();
        console.log( key + ": " + filtro_curso );
    });
```

Below are the result that I get from this code:

```
    Category 1
    Category 2
    Course 1
    Course 2
    Course 3
    Course 4
    Course 5
    Course 6
```

But I want to get result in this way

```
    Category 1
    Category 1 - Course 1
    Category 1 - Course 2
    Category 2
    Category 2 - Course 3
    Category 2 - Course 4
    Category 2 - Course 5
    Category 2 - Course 6
```

I can't modify the structure of the HTML page, I can only change the javascript/jquery code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop over the `.categoria_filtro` elements and use `nextUntil()` to get the following child courses. You can then loop over those courses and perform whatever logic you require, something like this:

```js
$('.categoria_filtro').each(function() {
  var category = $(this).text().trim();
  console.log(category);

  $(this).nextUntil('.categoria_filtro').each(function() {
    var course = $(this).text().trim();
    console.log(category + ' - ' + course);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filtro_informacoes">
  <div class="categoria_filtro">
    <b>Category 1</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 1</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 2</b>
  </div>

  <div class="categoria_filtro">
    <b>Category 2</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 3</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 4</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 5</b>
  </div>
  <div class="curso_filtro">
    <b>Course 6</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a fantastic way to go about it.

Comment: Very elegant solution to the problem. This is the first time that I see the use of the 'nextUntil' function of jquery.